# How to Pass value to Bootstrap model in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.1

I am trying to pass a value to the bootstrap model, but for each of the rows the edit button only displays the last row id. How can I display the edit button on each of the rows?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
@foreach($data as $cat_values)
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
        <td>{{$cat_values->cat_name}}</td>

          <td>{{$cat_values->cat_desc}}</td>
        <td>{{$cat_values->cat_slug}}</td>

          <td>{{$cat_values->created_at}}</td>
            <td>{{$cat_values->updated_at}}</td>

        <td><p  data-id="{{$cat_values->id}}" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
        <button data-id="{{$cat_values->id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit-page" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>
        <td><p  data-id="{{$cat_values->id}}" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs edit-page" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
           <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach;
```

And here is the model:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Edit Your Detail</h4>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="" />
        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="" value="{{$cat_values->cat_name}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="" value="{{$cat_values->parent_cat}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="">{{$cat_values->parent_cat}}</textarea>


        </div>
         <div class="form-group">

        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="" value="{{$cat_values->cat_desc}}">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">

        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="" value="{{$cat_values->cat_slug}}">
        </div>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Update</button>
      </div>
        </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
  </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>
```

How i can pass value to bootstrap model in Laravel? Thank you.

**Updated:**

```
 public function viewCategory()
    {

        $retrive=Category::all();
        $data=['data'=>$retrive];
        return view('a.view_category',$data);

    }
```

and in view if i print data

```
@foreach($data as $value)
{{$value->id;}}
{{$value->cat_name}}
{{$value->cat_desc}}
{{$value->cat_slug}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you do a fresh query and display the resuts without html, as well as show the query that you are running.

Comment: Quick note: don't use `@` to suppress error messages, especially when you're having a problem with an error!

Comment: @Tim.i am using laravel blade template.i hope its not an issue